# Automatically incrementing invoice numbers, resetting to zero each month

Tags: php, mysql, invoice

I have this issue I don't know how to create the invoice numbering. I would like it to work like this:

1. I download all invoices that have been paid from the table invoices, those with payment status OK.
2. I download the highest number from invoice_order, I add to it +1 and create the next numbers which mean the invoices numbers for those with payment=OK
3. Save new invoice numbers in the invoices/invoice_order table
4. And like this every time when there are new paid invoices so there is continuity in a given month

Do you have any ideas how to make this work?

```
    $year = date('Y'); 
    $month = date('m');
    $curent_date = date('Y-m-d');           

    $ask = $conn->createCommand("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE payment = 'OK' "
            . "AND invoice_month=$month AND invoice_year=$year");
    $data = $ask->query();  

    while (($row = $data->read()) !== FALSE) { 
        if($row['invoice_suffix'] != 'KOR') {

                echo $row['ID'].'<br>';  
        }          



    }
```

Comment: Why not just use an `auto_increment` column?

Comment: Because I want to have all invoices in one table. Auto increment means that I need have 12 tables for each month, is that right ? Could you please explain how invoices should be stored in a correct way ?

Comment: "Auto increment means i need to have 12 tables for each month" Why? You can literally just put everything in one table with a timestamp and status.

Comment: Auto increment did not work in this instance as he only wanted to increment a) when order status = OK and b) with each month resetting to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slightly difficult to understand the question but I think you want an invoice to receive a consecutive `order_number` once paid either a) regardless of when it's paid *OR* b) with the numbers resetting each month.

if A (every invoice_order is unique)

```
UPDATE invoices t1,
       (SELECT MAX(invoice_order)+1 as x FROM invoices WHERE payment = 'OK') t2
SET t1.payment = 'OK', t1.invoice_order = t2.x
WHERE t1.id = INVOICE_TO_BE_UPDATED;
```

if B (each month has a new set of repeated order numbers)

```
UPDATE invoices t1,
       (SELECT month, year, MAX(invoice_order)+1 as x FROM invoices WHERE payment = 'OK' GROUP BY month, year) t2
SET t1.payment = 'OK', t1.invoice_order = t2.x
WHERE t1.id = INVOICE_TO_BE_UPDATED AND t1.month = t2.month AND t1.year = t2.year;
```

Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ccS723rK7vCjdJBdDihjj6/0

Comment: Well, this is what I'm trying to do I want to give  a unique invoice number in the invoice_order column from 1 to X in each month and year. There is one table for all invoices named invoices. So my question is should I use just SQL query to update invoice_order column in the invoice table ? Thanks a lot for your anwsers guys ! :)

Comment: So use my option B above, it should work. You can test with `SELECT month, year, MAX(invoice_order)+1 as x FROM invoices WHERE payment = 'OK' GROUP BY month, year` and that should give you the correct ID for each month/year combination.

Comment: Yes, this solution works fine. Thank you very much, great job guys !